# Why is my POST request to google's api returning a redirect uri mismatch error?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

Beginner here. When trying to exchange my authorization grant for an access token to access google's api, i keep running into redirect uri mismatch error, however on checking my google cloud console, my authorized redirect uris are an exact match, including http and trailing slashes. My authorized javascript origin is also an exact match. The user authorization process goes fine and returns a code

Below is my code for the authorization process and the token exchange:

```py
@app.route("/youtubeauth")
def youtubeauth():
    yt_auth_dict={
        "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
        "client_id":youtube_client_id,
        "response_type":"code",
        "redirect_uri":"http://localhost:8888/tokenexchange",
        "prompt":"consent"
    }
    yt_auth_url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?"+urllib.parse.urlencode(yt_auth_dict)    
    print(yt_auth_url)
    return redirect (yt_auth_url)

@app.route("/tokenexchange")
def tokenexchange():

    code = request.args.get('code')
    if code:
        #obtaining access token
        print(code)
        params = {
            'code': code,
            'client_id': youtube_client_id,
            'client_secret': youtube_client_secret,
            'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8888/example',
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
            }
        
        tokenrequest=requests.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',data=params)
        return tokenrequest.json()
```

[Screenshot of my redirect uris:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iddMm.png)

Answer (score 0):

The redirect uri must exactly match one of the ones you have congired in google Developer console.  The error message will tell you what redirect uri your application is sending from.

[Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

Answer (score 0):

changing the redirect uri for exchanging the authorization code for an access token(/tokenexchange) to the same as that of prompting the user for authorization (/youtubeauth) worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).